# Crawling a website that uses angular routes

Tags: angularjs, web-crawler, sitemap, google-search, angularjs-routing

I have a personal website that I use for some of my motorbike racing. I created it recently using node and angular. I decided to try angular routes for my page navigation etc. I think it worked well but I'm annoyed that my website isn't showing on google search.

When I've looked into how to get google to find your website I've followed many suggestions with meta names etc but when I came to a sitemap I discovered that most crawlers etc have problems finding any links on my website to other pages.

You can see my website here - [MPC Racing](http://www.mpcracing.net)

I have tried using this automatic sitemap creator and it can't find anything apart from my main page - [XML Sitemap](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/)

Do you have any suggestions on how I can my website more easily found by search engines?

For example, a design company designed all my graphics for my bike and if I type into google "Webstep Racing Team" I get the link to their website as the first hit but nothing at all on my website. What is it they are doing and I'm not? - [Webstep Racing Team](http://www.kingdesign.no/identity/webstep-racing-team/#.U-HqZPuSyE4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the hashes are getting ignored by search engines, because normally they refer to parts of the same page.

You can follow [google guidelines for ajax crawling urls](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) to get the hashed url indexed by Google. The same standard also supported by [Bing](http://bing.com/) according to [searchEngineLand post](http://searchengineland.com/bing-now-supports-googles-crawlable-ajax-standard-84149).

And because you are using angularJs, you might find Matias Niemela's post on [how to have your AngularJS application indexed](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html) very useful. [Demo and source code](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-SEO-Article).

Answer (score 1):

In Google Webmaster tools there is an option to 'Fetch as google'. So you see what google sees when it crawls your angular app. It gives you an image of what google sees.

However for me the problem is that the crawler does not crawl the angular links within the app.

Comment: Well actually this is how i got my angular SPA indexed. Google Webmaster tools. Keep in mind that google (as far as i see) will not index your hashbang urls (like /#!/ ) so you need to build sitemap for them